# Javascript cookie information not being sent to the server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am saving some information on a form in a web application in a cookie like this.

```
           document.cookie = "FormInfo=" + data + ";"
```

This is passed through ajax to the server. On server side I am accessing the cookie information like this.

```
         if (Request.Cookies["FormInfo"] != null)
            {
                cookieObj = Request.Cookies["FormInfo"].Value;
                Request.Cookies["FormInfo"].Value = null;
            }
```

This used to work. Due to reasons unknown this is not working any more. Putting a break point on server side code and checking the cookie value - it shows null. The values in JS code are in tact, but somehow not persisting to the server any more. What could have happened? any ideas ? thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest you look in the network tab (in Chrome) for your ajax call and see what is and isn't being sent to your server.  Are you sending the cookie from the same page that you set it from?  Or might you have a path issue?  And, with no expiration time set, this will be a session only cookie.

Comment: I'm focusing on the "used to work" part: were there changes in the URL paths, either client-side or server-side? Did you switch from HTTP to HTTPS, or the inverse?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen no changes were done in the URL paths. No switching to HTTPS etc.

Comment: @jfriend00 good points.. I am checking.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes same page. No path issues.

Comment: Then, it sounds like your `document.cookie = xxx` line is perhaps not executing.  I'd suggest you look in the debug log for script errors.  And, put a `console.log("setting cookie");` right before the `document.cookie = xxx` line and see if that executes.

Comment: @jfriend00 we are seeing the cookie values in the network tab of chrome dev tools.

Comment: @EP2012 - OK, then you know it's being sent to the server.  The issue is on the server side somewhere.  I'm not an ASP.NET guy, but when I do a [quick Google search](http://developer.earthskater.net/asp/aspcookies.asp), I see code like this to read a cookie: `someValue = Request.Cookies("lastname")` which is different than what you have.

Comment: thanks.. we figured it out. Its a software we recently installed that is causing this issue. Uninstall fixed it.